Is it acceptable to copy the citations from another paper?
I am writing a paper about a PDE which I know to be relevant in many physical situations. Of course, when I say that "such PDE is important in physics in the field X and Y", it would be better to cite some relevant works. As you can imagine, the number of math papers that address the use of a PDE in a specific physical model is sometimes huge, and it is hard to find relevant ones by guessing a possible title and looking at the papers with similar names.
Now, topics very close to the one of my paper have been treated by much more experienced mathematicians whose work I cite because the connection is obvious. In one of such papers I found a good review of "where this particular PDE is used", with examples and references to various papers which I would have been unable to find myself.
The question is: what should I do? Is it acceptable to cite the same papers or is it better to only cite the work by this experienced mathematician and to write to "see the references there"? It seems to me that in the first case I am artificially pumping up the citations of the articles, possibly not citing some other works I would have found myself, but in the second case I am not citing relevant work which in theory should be cited.

I don't think evaluating this in terms of its affects on citation counts is productive. Rather one should forget about bibliometrics and think about what serves the reader and the scientific community. If you have nothing to add to the work by the experienced mathematician I would just cite it and say here the references herein, as literally copy-pasting would be a form of plagiarism and would contribute to problems where incorrect citations are sometimes repeated from one work to the next without checking.

On the other hand, if you are doing something to add value beyond just copy-pasting, such as reorganizing a list of citations to better explain the connections to your current work, and looking at the cited works at least briefly to see they are being cited correctly, it's fine to include a citation list very similar to prior work. Standards for what counts as plagiarism are necessarily more generous for copying citations because, for example, word-for-word identical citations are necessarily produce if two authors cite the same paper in the same citation style.

Let's say, the references in the other paper are somehow "scattered" among the introduction, while I put them all in the same place. I also checked each reference to be sure that it was really relevant

"For a good review of this material, including original (?) references, see X."

Given that a standard literature review involves finding references scattered around the literature, checking that they're relevant, and putting them in one place, this seems fine to me. I would certainly credit the other paper and direct the reader to it if they want a more detailed review.

Are you aware of existing survey paper on the topic you are dealing with? Because survey papers are very helpful in these cases. If it is so, you can cite the relevant examples referring to this paper (or these papers).
